# How to return logical vector "y" for two different conditions without using loops

Tags: r

I want to create a logical vector `y` that returns `TRUE` for the following conditions:

```
(1) For x1 >= 10, return value TRUE when x2 > 85
(2) For x1 < 10, return value TRUE when x2 > 75
```

```
Example dataset 

x1 = c(3,4,1,7,2,5,3,7,11,22,64,23,46,75,23,5,3)
x2 = c(43,56,87,54,77,65,87,56,76,79,70,77,78,79,85,54,67)
data = data.frame(x1,x2)
```

The data I am working with has more than what is presented in the example. I am dealing with 300 observations, but the logic works the same.

What I did was create a subset of x1>=10, x1 < 10 then find values that satisfy x2 > 85. Then created two conditions that satisfy the conditions.

```
over10 = data$x1 >= 10
less10 = data$x1 < 10

cond1 = over10[data$x2 > 85]
cond2 = less10[data$x1 < 75]

y = cond1 || cond2
```

I was actually hoping to have something like:

```
y = True,False,True,True,...
```

But what I got was:

```
y = TRUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with(data, (x1 >= 10 & x2 > 85) | (x1 < 10 & x2 > 75))

#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[14] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```